# EditText to CheckBox focus has not been changed

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, android-checkbox

In my application we have a scroll view in that we added CheckBox, ComboBox and SingleLineText elements. Each has separate class which extends CheckBox,ComboBox and EditText correspondingly.

In the SingleLineText we implemented `OnFocusChangeListener()` and `override onFocusChange()` method. If focus is in first SingleLineText and touch on the second SingleLineText then focus has changed. But if focus is in SingleLineText and touch on any check box or comboBox still focus(cursor) is in SingleLineText only. Because of that `onFocusChange()` method has not been called.

Can anybody has any idea about this problem?

Comment: Please add some code where you are trying to implement described functionality.

Answer (score 0):

call `yourEditText.clearFocus();` on other components like `CheckBox`, `ComboBox` click event method this will force to call your `onFocusChange()` method

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your activity in manifest file

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove focus from EditText by calling the following lines of code.

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

and call

```
checkBox.requestFocus();
```